# View wrapper causes to crash Android app in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I've been using react-native-maps library to show maps on my app, however, whenever I try to wrap MapView container with  it causes to crash my Android app. It doesn't show any errors.

The map looks good alone without View.

```
render() {
    return (
            <MapView style={styles.map}
                     // mapType='terrain'
                     showsUserLocation= {true}
                     region={{
                         latitude: this.state.userLat,
                         longitude: this.state.userLong,
                         latitudeDelta: 0.003,
                         longitudeDelta: 0.003,
                     }}>
                {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                    console.log(this.state.userLat),
                        <Marker
                            key={marker.id}
                            coordinate={marker.coordinates}
                            title={marker.title}
                            description={marker.description}
                        />
                ))}
            </MapView>
    );
}
```

When I add:

```
import {View, StyleSheet, BackHandler} from 'react-native';
```

and add wrappers:

```
    render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <MapView style={styles.map}
                     // mapType='terrain'
                     showsUserLocation= {true}
                     region={{
                         latitude: this.state.userLat,
                         longitude: this.state.userLong,
                         latitudeDelta: 0.003,
                         longitudeDelta: 0.003,
                     }}>
                {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                    console.log(this.state.userLat),
                        <Marker
                            key={marker.id}
                            coordinate={marker.coordinates}
                            title={marker.title}
                            description={marker.description}
                        />
                ))}
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

It crashes, no idea, what's wrong with my wrap.

Comment: Can you please add logcat from Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Apparentely, I had to set flex: 1 style on View. Works fine now!